# Java.Interop missing after upgrading to VS for Mac 8.5

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

BACKGROUND INFO: Project is using Xamarin.Forms 3.5 (due to inherited technical debt upgrading to 4.0+ breaks the app and client doesn't want to spend time to rewrite app right now).

PROBLEM: Upgraded VS for Mac to version 8.5 and now Droid project will not build.  Get an error saying Java.Interop assembly is missing.  Sure enough when I check under references Java.Interop is missing.  Does not seem to be available anywhere in Add References dialog.

EDIT: I was able to browse to the Java.Interop file using the following path but app still fails to compile after adding reference to file.  Filepath = ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Frameworks⁩ ▸ ⁨Xamarin.Android.framework⁩ ▸ ⁨Versions⁩ ▸ ⁨9.0.0-20⁩ ▸ ⁨lib⁩ ▸ ⁨xamarin.android⁩ ▸ ⁨xbuild-frameworks⁩ ▸ ⁨MonoAndroid⁩ ▸ ⁨v1.0⁩

Comment: Please search the `Java.Interop` in the reference manager like this sceenshot.https://imgur.com/a/6LuxMYe, If you still cannot get it, One temporary option is to ignore the error, but it is also safe to remove the reference to Java.Interop. For details(please see Brendan Zagaeski [MSFT]'s reply
):https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/678458/javainterop-issue.html

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Hey thanks for the recommendations, Java.Interop is not found when searching via add references dialog.  Deleted reference to Java.Interop but app still won't compile.  Build error is "Compilation can't be completed because some library classes are missing". File=R8.

Comment: Please change your android settings as this link:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180035/compilation-cant-be-completed-because-some-library-classes-are-missing-file-r8

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Changed settings; verified changes match screenshots multiple times but deploying app to the phone fails with following: ADB0010: Deployment failed.  Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/com.blah.blah.blah-sChM76tRPHIRLr5FKMA==/base.apk code is missing]

Comment: Attempted adb uninstall but that does not help either.  Comes back saying Unknown package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was continuing to research the deployment error I came across [this github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4437) where Brendan mentions changing AndroidDexTool to d8 (accepted answer on Xamarin forums uses dx). So on a whim I changed it back to d8, hit run and voila - it built and deployed with no errors.  Go figure.  Thanks for all your help!